# pacman: <filename> exists in filesystem

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

When installing a package with `pacman`, I am seeing:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
station: /usr/bin/station exists in filesystem
```

How do I tell `pacman` to install the package anyway, overwriting the existing file(s)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check what package includes the filename:

```
pacman -Qo filename
```

If it is another package, then file a bug report: packages which have conflicting files should mark themselves as `CONFLICTS` causing `pacman` to ask if you wish to replace the conflicting package.

If the files don't belong to any package, rename or delete them.

---

[If you're sure you know what you're doing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Avoid_certain_pacman_commands), you can use the `--overwrite` option, eg:

```
pacman -S package-name --overwrite /usr/bin/station
```

or

```
pacman -S package-name --overwrite '*'
```

The [man page](https://manned.org/pacman.8) says:

> ```
>    --overwrite <glob>
>        Bypass file conflict checks and overwrite conflicting files. If the
>        package that is about to be installed contains files that are
>        already installed and match glob, this option will cause all those
>        files to be overwritten. Using --overwrite will not allow
>        overwriting a directory with a file or installing packages with
>        conflicting files and directories. Multiple patterns can be
>        specified by separating them with a comma. May be specified
>        multiple times. Patterns can be negated, such that files matching
>        them will not be overwritten, by prefixing them with an exclamation
>        mark. Subsequent matches will override previous ones. A leading
>        literal exclamation mark or backslash needs to be escaped.
> ```

Comment: The Arch Wiki specifically [recommends avoiding `--overwrite`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Avoid_certain_pacman_commands) except as a last resort. The correct approach is to move the conflicting file(s) and complete the install.

Comment: Thanks, @jasonwryan, I've updated it. I actually had an AUR package conflicting with its own previously installed files - there may be some non-`pacman` auto-update going on which I'm still looking into.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use "*" as a glob, since it will overwrite absolutely anything including many things you didn't intend. The `--overwrite` option was added to pacman, and `--force` was removed, specifically because greedily matching everything was too dangerous and users got into trouble, whereas globs allow matching only what you need and know is okay.

Comment: @eschwartz In my case, it was ok to overwrite all files for the named package as all were named as conflicts.