# Pacman: cannot update my Linux packages (Arch/Manjaro): failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, manjaro, pacman

Trying to update my Manjaro system, I get "error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)"

This is pacman's output:

```
~> sudo pacman -Syu

Total Download Size:    4269.83 MiB
Total Installed Size:  17929.01 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       1517.05 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 iana-etc-20200720-1-any                         390.3 KiB  3.81 MiB/s 00:00 [############################################] 100%
 filesystem-2020.05-1-x86_64                      21.1 KiB  3.44 MiB/s 00:00 [############################################] 100%
 glibc-2.31-5-x86_64                               9.8 MiB  5.13 MiB/s 00:02 [############################################] 100%
...
 lib32-libva-mesa-driver-20.1.4-1-x86_64           2.6 MiB  3.50 MiB/s 00:01 [############################################] 100%
 lib32-mesa-demos-8.4.0-2-x86_64                 107.8 KiB  2.85 MiB/s 00:00 [############################################] 100%
(1363/1363) checking keys in keyring                                         [############################################] 100%
(1363/1363) checking package integrity                                       [############################################] 100%
(1363/1363) loading package files                                            [############################################] 100%
(1363/1363) checking for file conflicts                                      [############################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
cmake: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cmake exists in filesystem
cmake: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cpack exists in filesystem
cmake: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ctest exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

During the process, when asked whether to swap a package with another one, I always picked the default action.

What do those errors about `cmake` at the end mean?

How can I update my system?

Comment: The ArchWiki got you covered: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#%22Failed_to_commit_transaction_(conflicting_files)%22_error

Comment: @Devon - If you put it as a answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pacman: <filename> exists in filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490949/pacman-filename-exists-in-filesystem)

Comment: This worked for me (from the page you linked): `pacman -Qo /path/to/file` to check if the file is owned by another package, and if it is not (my case) rename or delete it.